# Can anyone explain how this wiring could work? (UK)

Tags: electrical, wiring, uk

This is how a bathroom lightswitch is currently wired... it works. But how?? (There's also a fan isolator switch supposedly connected to an extractor fan in the bathroom, but it apparently does nothing -- the fan never ran, even after it was replaced with a new unit.)

Thanks for any explanation!

[image: drawing of switch wiring]

Here's a photo, showing this wiring in action. And yes, it works fine. We can't understand how, or what the electrician who installed it was attempting to do.

[image: wiring from switch to wall]

### Update

Due to interest, here's the extractor fan's wiring:

[image: Fan switch wiring]

And the fan isolator switch's wiring:

[image]

And as a photo:

[image: isolation switch wiring]

It remains a mystery how they're all connected.

Comment: Does seem odd if using standard markings it does not trip breaker and the light works.  Imagine you are not seeing it right or someone made a mess.

Comment: It's odd for a switch to have "Live" and "Neutral" markings.   Usually the poles of the switch are symmetrical, they are "live" and "switched live" but only after you connect wires to them.   Until then there is no distinction.  (Your blue-with-black wires are probably switched live).   Perhaps this is not a simple switch.  Do you have the documentation?  The model number?  Is this two switches?

Comment: @jay613 Did the photo not load for you?

Comment: The black tape on the blue wires and blue paint( on purpose or sloppy) on one of the browns might mean something.  Knowing where they come from and go to would help also.

Comment: Ok .... when I blow up the photo I can see the markings clearly.

Comment: @crip659 There's an electrician booked for next week. Hopefully they can start to decipher this confusing situation!

Comment: It's always best to edit additional pics into your original post. They can get lost in comments. You can make a comment to let someone know you've added the pics.

Comment: @FreeMan Added some context. Thanks

Comment: it begins to make sense if you think of the switch as two separate switches ... L side is one ... N side is the other

Comment: @jsotola Interesting. Thanks. But why not just us L-N / L-N? And why make the neutral cables live (if that is what happened). I still can't wrap my head around it :)

Comment: Are you sure this is a double-pole switch, and not a double switch (2 switches in 1 frame)?  If you don't know what a double-pole switch is, this will be really confusing.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes, you can zoom in on the photo and see the words "Double Pole" clearly marked for yourself. This is what we *expected* to see when we opened it: https://images.socketsandswitches.com/images/content-images/double-pole-switch-wiring.jpg Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

This is marked as a "double pole" switch, and the terminals are marked "supply L&N" and "load L&N".

I think, with a little guessing, the switch is designed to isolate *both* the live and neutral sides of a device from power.  What kind of device, and why, is not clear to me.  If you know any local experienced electricians you could ask them how they've seen this kind of switch used in practice.

But the way it appears to be used in your house is to switch two different lighting circuits.   You have two switch loops there, operated together by one switch.   I can only guess why this would be done, rather than using a more typical pair of switches:

- Maybe the two circuits are on different breakers so cannot share a live wire.
- Maybe one switch loop controls the bathroom light, and the other the fan.  They are on two loops because that's how they were installed.  They were combined onto a double pole switch because that helps prevent users from using the bathroom without the fan, and from leaving the fan running after leaving.
- maybe the installer only had one of these switches in his van.  That's often the answer to many mysteries, but this would be an odd thing to have bouncing around in your van.

You could disconnect each blue wire, one at a time, to see what the two loops each control and whether they are on the same breaker circuit.

Comment: Thanks for attempting to understand this. It's very confusing! It's just the bathroom light switch. As I say there's also an isolation switch (with six wires, indicating a permanent live -- but I've no idea where that goes or what it's connected to). There's an extractor fan, but it only have two wires: Blue and Brown. (No permanent live.) And the it doesn't work.

Comment: Wild guess:  There are two switch loops to this switch, meant to be controlled by two switches but some previous user decided to put in a double pole switch for "convenience".   Nothing really wrong with that.    You could disconnect each blue wire in turn, to determine what is controlled by it.    Perhaps one is the fan, and the fan is broken.

Comment: @jay613  That is about the only thing that makes sense.  Would not be surprise if that is the answer.  Should have seen the black tape on neutrals as a clue.

Comment: @jay613 A new fan was just installed, so its not that... but it does appear to be two loops

Comment: @jay613  Would add your wild guess to the answer.

Comment: I added some info to the answer.   If the fan is new, maybe it was installed incorrectly.  If it was connected to the two sides of a switch loop as if one side was "neutral" by somebody who did not know it was a switch loop, that would cause it to not work.   However this explanation would require the installer to not even attempt to turn it on after.  Seems unlikely.  If the new fan WAS working and then STOPPED working ... I think that would need some local diagnostics with a meter.

Comment: @jay613 The fan has never worked as long as I've been here. I simply followed the wiring of the previous installation (Live + Neutral), thinking the fan was broken. Now I wonder if the polarity is backwards

Comment: @jay613 You can see the fan wiring here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUK4R.jpg

Comment: And the isolation switch here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5i1c.jpg

Comment: Are there more wires behind the fan?   The fan's terminal is labelled "permanent live"?  Is that right?  So how is it meant to be switched on and off?  Is there voltage between the fan's two wires?  I'm not familiar with what the "isolation switch" is for or how it works or is wired.

Comment: Think the brown and blue wires on the fan are probably the same ones on the odd switch.  If they are, you a need power cable for the fan to work, if those wires are the only ones to the fan.

Comment: @jay613 Yes! You are right. I found a photo of the fan before I installed it (literally the same model that had been there previously -- although never worked for me). It does say "Permanent Live" on it. Although that in itself is baffling because there's nothing else to this fan: No pullcord. No timer. No humidstat. It's the cheapest model you can buy: MANROSE NVF100S

Comment: @crip659 I'm beginning to think they are, too. But there's no other cables available near the fan. Ugh

Comment: I've seen the installation manual for this fan and I'm pretty sure that label that says "permanent" is just misleading.  It's for switched power and the manual clearly described that it's for switched power.  Their other models require both permanent and switched power.  I think for this model they just got the sticker wrong.

Comment: @jay613 Yep, I think you're correct about that

Comment: The fan was connected to a transformer. That's why the cables didn't match and why the fan didn't work: It was the wrong type.